# When is $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2) = \dim(W_1)$ for subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

To clarify my question:

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. What are the conditions that need to be satisfied in order to say that $\dim(W_1\cap W_2)=\dim(W_1)$?

I started by saying that if $W_1 \subseteq W_2$, then $W_1 \cap W_2=W_1$, in which case that $\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)$ must equal to $\dim(W_1)$. I also added the condition that the intersection of $W_1$ and $W_2$ can not be empty.

I'm having trouble trying to find out the conditions for other situations, like $W_1 \not\subset W_2$ and $W_2 \not\subset W_1$. I put down that if the basis of $W_1 \cap W_2$ has the order of $n$, then the basis of $W_1$ must have the same order. I'm not sure if I've done the right reasoning.

Any suggestion would help! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sketch of a proof: Given $W_1,W_2$ both subspaces of finite dimensional vector space $V$, we know from theorem that $W_1\cap W_2$ is also a finite dimensional subspace of $V$.  Pick a basis of $W_1\cap W_2$.  Such a basis can then be extended to be a basis of $W_1$.  If the basis of $W_1\cap W_2$ has strictly fewer basis elements than the basis for $W_1$ then clearly $dim(W_1\cap W_2)<dim(W_1)$., meanwhile if it has the same number of basis elements then it follows that the bases are the same and so $W_1\cap W_2=W_1$ and their dimension is the same.

Comment: "*I added the condition that the intersection of $W_1$ and $W_2$ can not be empty if $W_1$ is not empty*"  $W_1$ and $W_2$ are both subspaces and so they both contain at least the identity (*zero*) element, so neither are empty.